# How can we get an array of values for a particular key, from a sequence of objects inside an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to get an array of values for a particular key, from a sequence of objects inside an array using javascript.

Parent array

```
const a =[{employeeId: 033, field: "TAX", active: 1},
{employeeId: 035, field: "ACCOUNTING", active: 1},
 {employeeId: 035, field: "SALES", active: 1}];
```

Required output(array of values for the key named 'field')

```
["TAX","ACCOUNTING","SALES"]
```

Comment: ```const output = a.map(el=>el.field);``` Just a simple map()

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const a =[{employeeId: 033, field: "TAX", active: 1},
{employeeId: 035, field: "ACCOUNTING", active: 1},
 {employeeId: 035, field: "SALES", active: 1}];
const res = a.map(x => x.field);
// or a.map(({field})=>field);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please spend some with research if there isn't already a similar question, especially with such a common problem, instead of adding just another clone of an already available answer...

Answer (score 1):

`array.map` transforms an array for you.

```js
const a =[{employeeId: 033, field: "TAX", active: 1},
{employeeId: 035, field: "ACCOUNTING", active: 1},
 {employeeId: 035, field: "SALES", active: 1}];
 
 console.log(a.map((e) => e.field));
```